# LINQ to SQL extension method for sorting and paging

Tags: linq-to-sql, lambda

I have found an extension method that handles sorting and paging for [LINQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query). While this works well, I am trying to see if there are some other ways I can use this.

At present, the code for the [extension method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extension_method) is as follows:

```
public static IQueryable<T> Page<T, TResult>(
  this IQueryable<T> obj, 
  int page, 
  int pageSize, 
  System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<T, TResult>> keySelector, 
  bool asc, 
  out int rowsCount)
{
    rowsCount = obj.Count();

    int innerRows = (page - 1) * pageSize;

    if (asc)
        return obj.OrderBy(keySelector).Skip(innerRows).Take(pageSize).AsQueryable();
    else
        return obj.OrderByDescending(keySelector).Skip(innerRows).Take(pageSize).AsQueryable();
}
```

The method takes in an expression, which is based off the type.

In my Dealer class, I have a method GetDealers, which essentially calls this,
i.e.

```
db.User.Page(1, 2, p => p.User.UserProperty.Name, true, out rowCount)
```

From the presentation side of things though, I do not know or can access the expression as above, e.g.

```
ListView1.DataSource = users.GetDealers("SortColumn", pageNo, pageSize, out rowCount, bool asc);
ListView1.DataBind();
```

The only way is to have a switch statement in my GetDealers method that would then convert to the expression. Is there a way to bypass this, or is this method OK?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you're asking, but I believe it's something that I have looked into myself.  If you would like to know how to dynamically sort your results based on a string, rather than a proper LINQ expression, then you're in luck.

Scott Guthrie published a great [article](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx) on that very topic.  It references a Microsoft file which extends any `IQueryable` object to support dynamic sorting.
[C# Dynamic Query Library (included in the \LinqSamples\DynamicQuery directory)](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/bb894665.aspx).  Just add the page to your `App_Code` folder and include "Using System.Linq.Dynamic" in your project and you will be able to use the following syntax:

```
myUsers = myUsers.OrderBy("LastName");
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for extension method to work on all types

```
public static class SortingAndPagingHelper
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the list of items of type on which method called
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TSource">This helper can be invoked on IEnumerable type.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="source">instance on which this helper is invoked.</param>
    /// <param name="sortingModal">Page no</param>
    /// <returns>List of items after query being executed on</returns>
    public static IEnumerable<TSource> SortingAndPaging<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, SortingAndPagingInfo sortingModal)
    {
        // Gets the coloumn name that sorting to be done o`enter code here`n
        PropertyInfo propertyInfo = source.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0].GetProperty(sortingModal.SortColumnName);

        // sorts by ascending if sort criteria is Ascending otherwise sorts descending
        return sortingModal.SortOrder == "Ascending" ? source.OrderByDescending(x => propertyInfo.GetValue(x, null)).Skip(sortingModal.PageSelected * sortingModal.PageSize).Take(sortingModal.PageSize)
                           : source.OrderBy(x => propertyInfo.GetValue(x, null)).Skip(sortingModal.PageSelected * sortingModal.PageSize).Take(sortingModal.PageSize);
    }
}
```

`DbContext dbContext = new DbContext();
dbContext.rainingSessions.Where(x => x.RegistrationDeadline > DateTime.Now)                                                                         .SortingAndPaging(sortAndPagingInfo).ToList()`